How can I save quantum gates as a graphic in png/svg format using Qiskit?
I am working with Qiskit for programming quantum circuits. Everything works fine but there is one thing which I didn't find out.
Here is my Python code:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)

qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)

qc.draw(output = "mpl")

This is my output:

I am only interested into the graphical representation of the Hadamard gate (red one). I need it for a description. I don't need the wires and the qubits. How can I save the Hadamard gate as png/svg file using Qiskit?

This worked with me:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.visualization import circuit_drawer

qc = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc.h(0)
circuit_img = circuit_drawer(qc, output='mpl', scale=2)

circuit_img.savefig('hadamard_gate.png') # save figure as PNG
circuit_img.savefig('hadamard_gate.svg') # save figure as SVG

cf. https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.visualization.circuit_drawer for additional info

Thanks, but the picture contains the qubit "q" and the H gate. I just want the gate without everything else.

Qiskit has an API to save images from .draw: QuantumCircuit.draw(..., filename=...)
The following saves a file called h_gate.png (you can also do it with h_gate.svg):
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister

qc = QuantumCircuit(QuantumRegister(1, name=''))
qc.h(0)
qc.draw(output='mpl', filename='h_gate.png')


